# writing a file to a directory on a different network with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, networking

I need to be able to read and write files to a directory on my home network from a rails application hosted on heroku. Is it possible to do this with something like

```
File.open("publicIPaddress/path/to/directory", "w") {|f| f.puts logic to write }
```

Now i know I'm going to need an ddns since i have a dynamic IP address and that I'll need to assign a static IP to the machine on the network where the target directory is located but from here I'm not sure where to go. Is there a specific port i need to forward for reading a writing files to a network.

Additional info: The machine I'm attempting to read and write files to is running windows 7.

this is pretty out of my wheelhouse i don't know much about networking.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's possible but it is a very broad question; It's not just a matter of writing to a separate port, you need to have something listening on that port, then tell that app how to write the file. A better solution is probably pulling the file to your machine from the server. How you trigger than and what mechanisms to use require a broad answer.

Comment: What @theTinMan said. You'll need a server (e.g. FTP or SSH) on the publicIPaddress.

Comment: @theTinMan @EricDuminil so writing files with `File.open(IPaddress/path/to/dir)` Isn't an option? Is there a FTP or SSH service either of you know of that i should use?

Comment: You will also need to open the ports in your home router as well as your win box for whatever protocol you end up using. Otherwise the connection will be blocked. Additionally, try to use sftp or ssh and make sure you secure it properly as you are essentially opening up a door into your home network. Make sure whatever server you use in your home machine is secure and has a strong password. Once bots realize there is an sftp server there they will start trying to brute force their way in. Additionally, remove any default accounts that may come with the server and change ports if possible.